# Certain hall switch operation

Tags: hall-effect

I have a question regarding a [Hall sensor IC](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Magnetic-Digital-Position-Sensor-ICs/Hall-Effect-Unipolar-Switches/A1150-2-3-5-6-7-8.aspx).

I cant quite understand how is it possible that it can operate only on 2 wires, instead of 3. The way I can think of it is that 2 wires provide Vcc and gnd, and the 3rd one would be the sensind output on the sense resistor (see app note). Now, I know for a fact that it is used in 2 wire config, like Ccc + sensing wire without gnd. It seems confusing. On the schematic there is something like virtual earth inside the IC- does it mean that what hall effect occur when a magnet is close the loop closes inside the IC? I would appreciate an explanation -- but not about how does the Hall effect work, but how this certain IC does.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the "Functional Description" section of the datasheet, those Hall effect switches use an external sense resistor.

**EDIT:**

Like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjRcPh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And then you measure the voltage across Rsense.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19258/discussion-on-answer-by-ignacio-vazquez-abrams-certain-hall-switch-operation).